# Amazon MWS US Marketplace: How to get tax rate used on an order line?

Tags: amazon-mws

How do I get the tax rate or tax rate's that were used to calculate a tax amount on an order line with Amazon MWS?

In the Orders API there is an ItemPrice and ItemTax XML element but these only contain the amounts rather than the rate used.

I need to know what rate or rate's were used to calculate the ItemTax and what state these taxes apply too. I also need to get this information programmatically via the MWS API.

In the MWS Reports API I have tried many reports trying to find this information.

- _GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_ does not contain tax rate/state
- _GET_FLAT_FILE_SALES_TAX_DATA_ This report can't be requested or scheduled. We don't have access to the users seller central account because we are developing an integration.
- _SC_VAT_TAX_REPORT_ I can't use this because it is not for US
- _GET_VAT_TRANSACTION_DATA_ I can't use this because it is not for US

For example from the Orders API ListOrderItems

```
<ItemTax>
  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
  <Amount>0.81</Amount>
</ItemTax>

<ItemPrice>
  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
  <Amount>12.99</Amount>
</ItemPrice>
```

If you try calculate backwards to the rate

0.81 / 12.99 = 0.0623556581986143

This isn't accurate because the ItemTax has already been rounded to 2 dp and I also need to know what state this tax was calculated from.

Comment: That's a great question.  We've never needed to know the exact rate or source of the tax, but this is problematic anyway because the rate applied is so variable - you have state tax, city tax and those can very depending on business vs residential.  I don't imagine the breakdown is available to you, so you'd have to calc it like you did.   There might be a tax service you can call that would tell you rates, but you'd have to google that.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to calculate tax rate is to use the following formula:

```
tax_rate = -1 + gross_price / (gross_price - tax)
```

In your example:

```
gross_price = 12.99
tax = 0.81

tax_rate = -1 + 12.99 / (12.99 - 0.81) = -1 + 12.99 / 12.18 = 0,0665024630541 ≈ 6,65%
```

Still this solution is prone to rounding errors but should be more accurate.